# setSQL not working in CartoDB API?

Tags: carto

I'm trying to use CartoDB API to retrieve a dataset from my account to a heatmap. I want to filter the data using SQL. The problem is the following: the sql query does not always work when using the on done callback. However, it does work when I set it from the console using the map variable (where I stored the layer).

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
.addTo(map)
.on('done', function(layer) {
    map.layer = layer;    
    layer.getSubLayer(0).set(subLayerOptions); // sql is inside here
    map.invalidateSize(true);
}).on('error', function() {
    console.error("Cannot create layer");
});
```

### EDIT

I wrote another cartodb code in the example, the actual sentence which sets the sql is this one: `layer.setSQL(subLayerOptions.sql);` (as it is a heatmap and the torque layer seems not to have the getSubLayer function).

To clarify my question, the result I'm obtaining is the same as if I don't set the query in the done callback (as I assume it is using the sql I have in the map I created from CartoDB SaaS). It is **ignoring** the query passed through javascript. I remark that if I set it later it works fine, it just needs some time to load the first time so I assume the problem is around that but I haven't find it yet.

### EDIT 2

Sometimes the fix is just to zoom in and out. In this cases the data seems to be loaded but the interface is not refreshing.

Comment: Please ask your new edited comments in a new question if the first one was solved.

Comment: It was not answered, I just added information I found that could help solve the issue.

Comment: If you could share your code or create a repo to have a look. Because with this info I cannot replicate your problem. Be careful with `subLayerOptions.sql`, if this is a local file your code will not work.

Answer (score 1):

With the little info you have told us the only thing I came up is removing `map.layer = layer`. Also I do not know what are you trying to do with `map.invalidateSize(true);`. Nevertheless, I have created [a working example](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/dacb85d6854403376fc3a53872258804) about setting the options of a sublayer. And the sql query works every time! :-)

Comment: Sometimes my maps are initialized while hidden and when I show them up the size is wrong, so I invalidate it to fix the problem.